# Why i can't get GPS data from TTGO-TBEAM-T22_V1.1? Is there any problem with my GPS MODULE?

Tags: arduino, embedded, esp32

`

```
#include <axp20x.h>

#include <TinyGPS++.h>                       

TinyGPSPlus gps;                            
HardwareSerial MySerial1(1);                 

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  MySerial1.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, 34, 12);   //17-TX 18-RX
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.print("Latitude  : ");
  Serial.println(gps.location.lat(), 5);
  Serial.print("Longitude : ");
  Serial.println(gps.location.lng(), 4);
  Serial.print("Satellites: ");
  Serial.println(gps.satellites.value());
  Serial.print("Altitude  : ");
  Serial.print(gps.altitude.feet() / 3.2808);
  Serial.println("M");
  Serial.print("Time      : ");
  Serial.print(gps.time.hour());
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(gps.time.minute());
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.println(gps.time.second());
  Serial.println("**********************");

  smartDelay(1000);                                      

  if (millis() > 5000 && gps.charsProcessed() < 10)
    Serial.println(F("No GPS data received: check wiring"));
}

static void smartDelay(unsigned long ms)                
{
  unsigned long start = millis();
  do
  {
    while (MySerial1.available())
      gps.encode(MySerial1.read());
  } while (millis() - start < ms);} `
```

I tried everything to get the data but, the only thing i get is this Serial Monitor Print ;

```
**15:02:38.225 -> No GPS data received: check wiring
15:02:38.225 -> Latitude  : 0.00000
15:02:38.225 -> Longitude : 0.0000
15:02:38.225 -> Satellites: 0
15:02:38.225 -> Altitude  : 0.00M
15:02:38.225 -> Time      : 0:0:0**
```

This code is belongs to offical github account of my TTGO-TBEAM. THE RX-TX PINS are Right.IT Still does not work.

Do i make something wrong? or just my gps is broken ?

Comment: How long did you leave it to run? Depending on your location it might take several minutes before the GPS picks up a signal.

Comment: Are you using the correct serial pins? The comment `//17-TX 18-RX` seems to conflict with the actual parameters.  Unhelpfully the code at https://github.com/LilyGO/TTGO-T-Beam/blob/master/GPS/GPS.ino has the same comment but uses pins 12 and 15 !?  The Schematic at https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/LilyGo-LoRa-Series/blob/master/schematic/LilyGo_TBeam_V1.1.pdf says IO12 (RXD) and IO34 (TXD).  Seems to be confused all round.  Add links to the code and schematic you are using if different form these.

Comment: @OliverMason : That was my first thought, or no sky view, but the `No GPS data received: check wiring` message is output when there is no serial data, even with no position fix the ublox Neo module will output data.

Comment: ... https://tinymicros.com/wiki/TTGO_T-Beam states pins 12 and 15 not 12 and 34 - but that conflicts with any schematic I can find.  Bad documentation one way or another it seems.

Comment: @Clifford , There is a model differences. In TTGO T22_v1.1 USES  12-34 for TX-RX. But the code above it uses 12-15.

Comment: @Tortudereli I've no doubt. Just pointing out the ambiguity.  Are you certain the model you have been supplied is the version you state?

Comment: @Clifford No worries Cliff. It is T22_V1.1

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem, but I finally managed to resolve it.

- For the problem of the GPS not receiving valid data (ie the LED does not blink), go to an open-air location.
- For the problem of GPS not showing anything, read this repository and follow the README step by step: https://github.com/eriktheV-king/TTGO_T-beam_GPS-reset

My GPS started to work running only the v3 code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Especially point 2 ultimately helped me out! Buth both are quite important indeed.